# Method for checking Mode

Tags: java, methods, mode

I have this method here, checking for the Mode (most frequent element) in an array. Although there is a twist I need to account for and i'm not sure how to go about doing this. For example: if my array is {1,2,2,3,3,5} .. I need to print out 'NaN' , because 2 and 3 both occur 2 times. Any help on how to add this is appreciated.

My code:

```
  public double mode() {
    double maxValue=0, maxCount=0;
    boolean flag=false;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) 
        {
            double count = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < data.length; ++j) 
                    {
                        if (data[j]==(data[i])) ++count;
                    }
                if (count > maxCount)
                {
                        if(count>1)flag = true;
                        maxCount = count;
                        maxValue = data[i];
                }
        }
        if(flag)
        {
            return maxValue;
        }
        else return 0.0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your current code is not exactly giving out the result you wanted.

Here's a code snippet updated:

```
public double mode() {
        // Sort array
        Arrays.sort(data);

        double maxValue = 0.0, maxCount = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

            // Count number of elements with same value
            int count = 0;
            int index = i;  
            while (index < data.length) {
                if (data[i] == data[index]) {
                    count++;
                    index++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (count > maxCount) {
                maxCount = count;
                maxValue = data[i];
            } else if (count == maxCount) {
                maxCount = count;
                maxValue = 0.0;
            }
        }

        return maxValue;
    }
```

Then, from the point where you call `mode()`, do the following:

```
double m = mode();
System.out.println(m == 0.0 ? "NaN" : m);
```

Comment: This code seems a lot better than mine, although I'm not able to put the second little bit into my main method. Is there someway to incorporate it into the method? If m==0.0, can I print out "NaN" instead of the 0.0?

Comment: Can you show how you called this method from your `main`? If you are talking about `public static void main(String[] args)`, you will have to make `mode()` a static method.

Comment: Oh i figured it out. Apparently I can set maxValue to Double.NaN on the else statement. Thank you for ur help with the rest of the code though!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you return `0.0` when you don't find a mode, how about using this ternary when you call the `mode()` function:

```
final double mode = this.mode();
System.out.println(mode == 0.0 ? "NaN" : mode);
```

Or to put it in full if you prefer:

```
final double mode = this.mode();
if(mode == 0.0)
{
    System.out.println("NaN");
}
else
{
    System.out.println(mode);
}
```

Comment: I understand your code, but where would I go inserting it? My method needs to be return type double.

Comment: @Nadal Wherever you're calling `mode()`, or if you can't put it there then in the final `else` statement of the `mode()` method.